# Can InfoPath display specific user information after selecting someone in people picker

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, people-picker, infopath-rules

I am using InfoPath 2013 to create a form for SharePoint online.

I want to use the `'Person/Group Picker'` to select an employee and have InfoPath display various specific details about that person (which it pulls from active directory). Things like Location, phone number, etc.

This info could either be all in one field or separated out into separate fields (one field for location, one for the phone number, etc).

I don't see any option for it to display anything other than the name. Is there a way to have it display more details?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `http://yoursitename/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx` to retrieve the related AD information for a specific user based on its AccountName as the following:

- In Data tab, Create a data connection from `Web Service` >  `SOAP Web Service`.

[image]

- Select Receive Data > Click Next > Add `UserProfileService` web service URL
  via `http://yoursitename/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx?WSDl`
- Select Get `GetUserProfileByName`

[image]

- Now you can Create a rule to get the related information based on user account as mentioned at [GetUserProfileByName at infopath](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/)

---

**[Update]**

In Parameter page set the value of the people picker field

[image]

Follow the detail steps at [GetUserProfileByName at infopath](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Unless i missed something...This looks like it will only tell the info of the user filling out the form. I am trying to have it display info of the person that is selected in the people picker